# Como usar decrement no laravel 5.2 usando dados de um array?

Tags: laravel

Estou usando o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) à alguns meses e me deparei com o seguinte problema de controlar o estoque após a compra automaticamente.

A lógica do meu sistema é a seguinte:

Após a compra de um produto na minha loja automaticamente decrementar a quantidade selecionada pelo usuário no ato da compra, o sistema funciona corretamente quando só tem um item no carrinho, quando tem dois itens ou mais o sistema altera apenas um, minha dúvida é como fica o código para recuperar e manipular todos os ítens através de uma array, segue o código:

**arquivo.blade.php**

```
@foreach($produtos as $produto)
 ...
Os valores a seguir estão dentro de um input, que são enviados por um formulário (acrescentei as [] em ambos).

    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{ $produto['item']['id'] }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="qtde[]" value="{{ $produto['quantidade'] }}">
...
@endforeach
```

**MeuController.php**
minha dúvida ainda é neste arquivo, alterei e está assim:

```
public function funcao(Request $request)
{

DB::table('produtos')
    ->where(['id', $request->get('id')])
    ->decrement(['quantidade', $request->get('qtde')]);

}
```

e como já de se esperar retornou o seguinte erro:

> strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Mostra os inputs do formulario por completo sff

Comment: O erro está ai deves enviar um array, name="id[]" e o mesmo para a qtd, depois do lado servidor trabalhas isso num foreach

Comment: Ok, obrigado por responder tão rápido, poderia me dar algum exemplo de como fica o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os ids e as quantidades já vão ser um array do lado servidor,
O que tens de fazer depois quando recebes os dados no teu controller é:

```
...
foreach($request->get('id') as $key => $id) {
    if(isset($request->get('qtde')[$key]) && is_numeric($request->get('qtde')[$key])) {
        DB::table('produtos')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->decrement('quantidade', $request->get('qtde')[$key]);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: De nada @jardelfrank, ainda bem que ajudei. Marque a resposta como aceite sff, por baixo das setas cima/baixo à esquerda da resposta

Comment: Estava mesmo procurando onde fazer isso, a primeira vez que faço pergunutas aqui e espero voltar para retribuir logo : ) mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: Hehe bem-vindo @jardelfrank